# What does this long yellow sign mean in Indonesia?

Tags: culture, indonesia

When moving around Indonesia, I have noticed that some houses have this sign sometimes:

[image: Strange items seen in Indonesia]

What does it mean? Is it just a decoration or does it have some meaning?

Comment: A blog post about the topic: http://thedailyroar.com/culture/janur-kuning-a-staple-of-indonesian-ceremonies/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best I can figure this there is a party of some sort going on at the house that [arrow is pointing to](http://thedailyroar.com/culture/janur-kuning-a-staple-of-indonesian-ceremonies/).  The [Janur Kuning](http://thedailyroar.com/culture/janur-kuning-a-staple-of-indonesian-ceremonies/) is traditional ornaments, not to be confused with the Movie under the same name, that appear to designate the house where a celebration or a ceremony takes place.

The particular image that you posted is also visible on [Wikipedia's French Page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%AAte) for Party.  Most commonly I found this type of symbol to be referring to or used in conjunction with a wedding.

Comment: Yeah, the sign even says "Pillun & Anah"

Comment: usually this is a sign of wedding. I guess Pillun & Anah is the name of the bride.

Answer (score 10):

It is put up in front of the bride's house before the wedding.

UPDATE: As I was asked for reference... I am currently staying in Indonesia and showed the picture to my local friends. They told me about the meaning. I also asked whether it's just common here in Java (because in indonesia every region has it's own traditions), and they replied it is common in all of indonesia.

Comment: Welcoem to Travel.SE! Care to elaborate? We really like answers to provide some backing, or references if possible - more than just a short sentence :)

Comment: Actually this is only applicable for Javanese people. It is not common in some place of Indonesia, unless one of the bride is Javanese...

Answer (score 4):

This is like a sign that there a marriage ceremonial is held in that area. This sign is called "[Janur Kuning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janur_Kuning)" and mostly placed in main gate or alleyway which link with main access (road etc.)

Answer (score 1):

its kind of traditional ornament when some one get married

Comment: Hi, it sounds concise, but maybe you can explain a little bit more, like what it represents regarding marriage.